# Stop container instances group when one of the containers is terminated

Tags: azure, containers, azure-container-instances

I am creating a container group with a container that runs E2E on a website. How can I stop the entire group when one of the containers have stop running? (in this case the E2E tests)

I am creating this through a pipeline and I need to stop the front end container one the test are done.

```
apiVersion: 2018-10-01
location: northeurope
name: e2e-uat
properties:
  containers:
    # name of the instance in Azure.
    - name: e2etestcafe
      properties:
        image: registry.azurecr.io/e2e/e2etestcafe:latest
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 1
            memoryInGb: 3
    - name: customerportal
      properties:
        image: registry.azurecr.io/e2e/customerportal:latest
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 1
            memoryInGb: 1
        ports:
          - port: 80
  osType: Linux
  restartPolicy: never
tags: null
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, the ACI does not have the feature that you expect as I know. So you need to check the containers' state yourself.

I recommend you create a script with a loop to check the containers' state until it meets the situation you expect, then stop the whole container group. In the Azure DevOps, you can use the release pipeline with three stages, one for creation, second for checking the state with running the script, third for stop the container group.

To check the containers' state, I think the CLI command is helpful below:

```
az container show -g myResourceGroup -n myContainerGroup --query containers[*].instanceView.currentState.state
```

It will output all the containers' state in an array.